# SQL Server 2008 R2 : Truncate Permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, truncate

Can SQL commands like `truncate` be restricted at the user level (for specific databases / servers)?

A member of my team truncated a production table thinking he was in his development database and I would like to prevent this from happening again (without completely locking down his permissions).

Comment: Just a comment, I like to use the status bar color connection options to keep me cognizant of whether the query is being executed in test, dev, or prod. I usually use the bright red for prod. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1871/customizing-the-status-bar-for-each-sql-server-ssms-connection/

Comment: @brian: I agree with you. This is an excellent visual cue to constantly remind about the environment. I put production as red. But I had a junior developer stubborn enough not to follow it despite the apparent benefits.

Answer (score 4):

You might try adding a tinyint field (default 0) to the table you wish to protect, and adding a foreign key constraint pointing to a dedicated, single record table. That should protect your table.

That said, you should probably get rid of this guy.

Comment: +1 for something tricky that would still allow deletes and other operations, but would prevent a truncate.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember revoking `ALTER` permission on the table should do the trick (in all versions 2005 through 2012).

Comment: 2008 R2; caught that right as I clicked submit and don't see a way to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

A person needs DDL permission on a table to do a TRUNCATE, since it's an unlogged operation. Even if a person has datawriter (or insert/update/delete), but lacks ALTER or DDL_ADMIN, they won't be able to truncate the table.